# Likes counter doesnt update on other client (Laravel + Vue + Redis + Soket.io + Node)

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io, vuejs2

I try to make realtime app. When the user clicks the like button, the likes counter is updated. Now this only works for the current user. But another user does not see that the number of likes has changed (if it is connected via another browser, for example).

After hit like button I see at terminal server messages:

```
Message received: {"event":"App\\Events\\PostLiked","data":{"result":1,"socket":null},"socket":null}
```

But the likes counter updates only for one user on current browser.
I have maked **two Vue Components**:
1. Like button (that likes a post) - **LikePost.vue**
2. Like counter label (that shows the likes count) - **LikePostCount.vue**

This is [screenshot](https://ibb.co/hs9ZT6H)

I use **Laravel 5.5 + Vue JS 2.5.16**

I have installed this libraries and packets:

- node
- redis-server
- express 4.16.3
- ioredis 3.2.2
- socket.io 2.1.1
- socket.io-client 2.2.0

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('news-action');
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
 console.log('Message received: ' + message);
 console.log('Channel :' + channel);
 message = JSON.parse(message);
 io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port: 3000');
});
```

**/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

try {
       require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.events = new Vue();

window.flash = function (message) {
    window.events.$emit('flash', message);
};

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueNoty from 'vuejs-noty'

//connects events bus
export const bus = new Vue();
Vue.use(VueNoty)
```

**/resources/assets/js/app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('likepost', require('./components/LikePost.vue'));
Vue.component('likepostcount', require('./components/LikePostCount.vue'));

app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**/resources/assets/js/components/LikePost.vue**

```
<template> 
        <span>

            <button v-if="isliked" 
                @click.prevent="dislike(post_id)"
                type="button" 
                class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs" 
                name="like-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            </button>
            <button v-else
                @click.prevent="like(post_id)" 
                type="button" 
                class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" 
                name="like-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o">
                        </i>
                </button>

        </span>    
 </template> 

<script>
    import { bus } from '../bootstrap';
    import 'vuejs-noty/dist/vuejs-noty.css'
    export default {
        props: ["post_id", "liked"],

        data: function() {
            return { 
                isliked: '',
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.isliked = this.islike ? true : false;
        },
        computed: {
            islike() {
                return this.liked;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            like(post_id) {
            axios
                .post('/blog/posts/like/' + post_id)
                .then(response => { this.isliked = true; 
                      bus.$emit('postliked');
                })
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            },
            dislike(post_id) {
            axios
                .post('/blog/posts/like/' + post_id)
                .then(response => { this.isliked = false; 
                                    bus.$emit('postliked'); 
                })
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

**/resources/assets/js/components/LikePostCount.vue**

```
<template> 
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{ likescount }}
        </span>    
 </template> 

<script>
    import { bus } from '../bootstrap';
    import 'vuejs-noty/dist/vuejs-noty.css'
    export default {
        props: {
            post_id: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: () => {}
                }
            },

        data: function() {
            return { 
                likescount: 0,
            }
        },

        created(){
            bus.$on('postliked', (data) => {
               this.updatelikescount(this.post_id); 
            });
        },
        mounted : function() {
            var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
            socket.on("news-action:App\\Events\\NewEvent", function(data) {
                this.likescount = data.result;

            }.bind(this));

           this.updatelikescount(this.post_id);

        },

        methods: {

            updatelikescount(post_id) {

            axios
                .get('/blog/post/likecount/' + post_id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.likescount = response.data.data[0][0]
                })        
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
             },

        }
    };
</script>
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/LikeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Like;
use App\BlogPost;
use App\Events\PostLiked;

class LikeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('forbid-banned-user');
    }

    public function likePost($id)
    {
        // here you can check if product exists or is valid or whatever

        $this->handleLike('App\BlogPost', $id);
        $post = BlogPost::find($id);
        $like_count = $post->likes->count();
        event(new PostLiked($like_count));
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function handleLike($type, $id)
    {
        $existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->whereLikeableType($type)->whereLikeableId($id)->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();

        if (is_null($existing_like)) {
            Like::create([
                'user_id'       => Auth::id(),
                'likeable_id'   => $id,
                'likeable_type' => $type,
            ]);
        } else {
            if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at)) {
                $existing_like->delete();
            } else {
                $existing_like->restore();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**/app/Events/PostLiked.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class PostLiked implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $result;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->result = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return ['news-action'];
    }
}
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/BlogPostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\BlogPost;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BlogPostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function postGetLikesCountEvent(BlogPost $post)
    {
        //dd($request);
        $data2[] = [
            $post->likes->count()
        ];

        return Response::json([
            'data' => $data2
        ], 200);

    }
}
```

**/routes/web.php**

```
<?php
//BlogPost - likes - Like button clicked
Route::post('blog/posts/like/{post}', 'LikeController@likePost');
//BlogPost - likes - get likes count
Route::get('blog/post/likecount/{post}', 'BlogPostController@postGetLikesCountEvent');
```

Answer (score 0):

there was an error in the name of the event at **LikePostCount.vue**

fixed

```
socket.on("news-action:App\\Events\\NewEvent"...
```

to

```
socket.on("news-action:App\\Events\\PostLiked"
```